# Cannot access methods Newtonsoft.JSON .Net Core 2.*

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm have a solution with multiple projects all using .Net Core 2.1 (VS 2017). 
I can use Newtonsoft.JSON.JsonConvert in my web project without any problem for serializing and deserializing objects.

Another project in the same solution has the same Nuget packages (version and SDK) as my web project. 
Intellisense recognizes JsonConverter, but the only method that shows is Equals, so no SerializeObject or DeserializeObject.

When I open the JsonConvert Definition within my console application it has the namespace **Newtonsoft.Json** and a **public abstract class JsonConverter**

When I do the same within the web project I get the namespace **Newtonsoft.Json** and a **public static class JsonConvert**

The last one contains the methods I want to use, but I've no idea why this problem is occurring and how to solve it.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the error or a sample code.

Comment: have you tried running `dotnet restore` in your project folder?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I needed JsonConvert instead of JsonConverter...