# Cannot apply attribute class 'JsonConverter' because it is abstract

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON library and I'm trying to deserialize a JSON. The problem is that when I use `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` I get this error: `Cannot apply attribute class 'JsonConverter' because it is abstract`.

Here are my classes:

```
 public class ActionRepository
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum AllowedActions
    {
        FINDWINDOW,
    }

    public enum AllowedParameters
    {
        WINDOWNAME,
    }
}



public class Action
{
    public AllowedActions Name { get; set; }
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

I get the squiggly line under the `JsonConverter`.

EDIT: The JsonConverter class is indeed abstract if I navigate to the class (ctrl+click in VS). I'm using .NET for Windows Universal.

Comment: `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` doesn't apply an attribute of type `JsonConverter`, it applies the attribute [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConverterAttribute.cs) which is **not** abstract.

Comment: From the [c# language spec: Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes): *By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of `Attribute`. An attribute_name of the form type_name may either include or omit this suffix. If an attribute class is found both with and without this suffix, an ambiguity is present, and a compile-time error results.*  So it's odd that the IDE somehow thought `JsonConverter` was being applied rather than `JsonConverterAttribute`.  Possibly an IDE bug here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that when **not** targeting a .Net framework application - the `JsonConverter` class is marked as abstract.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53701226/985012) looks to be to use `JsonConvert` as an alternative.

Comment: Silly idea, but since it's abstract what if you just make your own subclass and use that?